# Prevent software and browsers from recognizing my laptop as tablet

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, tablet-pc

My laptop is a Dell XPS L502X. I no longer care that it's a tablet PC.

So, I installed Windows 7 Ultimate on it and tried to the best of my abilities to disable anything that makes it a tablet PC.

However, sometimes when I touch the display with my fingers, it recognizes it as a click, yet I specifically disabled that input.

Secondly, Chrome somehow still thinks it's a tablet and displays websites as if they are touch-enabled, such as GMail and some news sites.

**What is the complete checklist to disable these behaviors?**

Comment: Among your settings, did you disable: (1) "Use your finger as an input device" in "Pen and Touch", (2) The service "Tablet PC Input" in system Services, (3) Use regedit to set in "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch]" the TouchGate item to 0.

Comment: What do your [browser headers have to say](http://browser-information.online-domain-tools.com/)? Does Modernizr [detect it as a touch capable device](http://stevengliebe.com/2013/09/13/online-test-browser-touch-capability/)? Also, try setting **Enable touch events** to **Disabled**. You can do this by following this link: `chrome://flags/#touch-events`

Comment: In addition to what @harrymc wrote, try [disabling any touch screen HID devices from the Device Manager](http://lifehacker.com/disable-your-laptop-s-touch-screen-in-windows-8-1-1588333600).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the second part of the question: **How to prevent web browsers from recognizing a laptop as a touch enabled device?**

### Google Chrome

1. Visit the internal Flags page and set **Enable touch events** to **Disabled**.

   ```
   chrome://flags/#touch-events
   ```
2. Restart Google Chrome.

### Firefox

1. Enter `about:config` in the address bar, click **I'll be careful, I promise!**
2. Enter `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` in the search bar and change the preference value to [**0** for **disabled**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25494516).
3. Restart Firefox.

Additionally, you can also test whether or not Modernizr detects your browser as touch capable by visiting this link: [Online Test for Browser Touch Capability](http://stevengliebe.com/2013/09/13/online-test-browser-touch-capability/)